# Adding complete Stripe payment requirement to form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am creating a platform, where friends can buy friends Starbucks.

Users create a request & other users can fulfill these requests by paying $5, then the requesting user receives a Starbucks gift card of $5.

Right now the only requirement to fulfill a request is the message text form (submitting without will throw an error) & I need to add the requirement of completing the Stripe payment before submitting the fulfill request form.

Ideally, I would like the fulfill the request button to be disabled until the Stripe payment is complete.

Fulfill Request form:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fulfillRequest, clearErrors } from 'redux/actions/dataActions';

import { Elements } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import CheckoutForm from '../FulfillRequest/Stripe/CheckoutForm';

class FulfillRequest extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    body: '',
    errors: {}
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.UI.errors
      });
    }
    if (!nextProps.UI.errors && !nextProps.UI.loading) {
      this.setState({ body: '', open: false, errors: {} });
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.props.clearErrors();
    this.setState({ open: false, errors: {} });
  };
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.fulfillRequest(this.props.requestId, { body: this.state.body });
  };
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      UI: { loading }
    } = this.props;
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <IconButton onClick={this.handleOpen} color="inherit">
          <TagFaces />
        </IconButton>

        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
          fullWidth
          maxWidth="sm">
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Fulfill request</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>

            <Elements>
              <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>

            <Grid
              container
              spacing={0}
              direction="column"
              alignItems="center"
              justify="center">
              {errors.error && (
                <FormHelperText error className={classes.customError}>
                  {errors.error}
                </FormHelperText>
              )}
            </Grid>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                autoFocus
                margin="dense"
                multiline
                placeholder="say something"
                id="name"
                name="body"
                label="say something"
                type="text"
                fullWidth
                error={errors.body ? true : false}
                helperText={errors.body}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button type="submit" color="primary" disabled={loading}>
                  Fulfill Request
                  {loading && <CircularProgress />}
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </form>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

FulfillRequest.propTypes = {
  fulfillRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  requestId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  clearErrors: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  UI: state.UI
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fulfillRequest, clearErrors }
)(withStyles(styles)(FulfillRequest));
```

Stripe Element:

```
class CheckoutForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { complete: false };
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  async submit(ev) {
    let { token } = await this.props.stripe.createToken({ name: 'Name' });
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://us-east1-foodmigo-v01-101.cloudfunctions.net/api/charge',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: token.id
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) this.setState({ complete: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.complete) return <h1>Purchase Complete</h1>;
    return (
      <div className="checkout">
        <p>Would you like to be a hero?</p>
        <CardElement />

        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={this.submit}>
          Send
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your Button component is composed, but couldn't you just pass it a prop of `disabled={!this.state.complete}`?

**EDIT:** Misunderstood the structure of the components.  That will still work though, however you'll need to raise the state indicating completion up out of your Form component into the `FulfillRequest` component so it can access it.  Your state for `FulfillRequest` should look something like:

```
state = {
    open: false,
    body: '',
    errors: {},
    complete: false,
  };
```

Then you can create a function which sets the value in that parent and pass it to the child form:

```
  setComplete = (val) => {
    this.setState({
      complete: val
    })
  }

...

<CheckoutForm setComplete={this.setComplete} complete={this.state.complete}/>
```

Then call the passed function to set the complete state when the form resolves with success:

```
  async submit(ev) {
    let { token } = await this.props.stripe.createToken({ name: 'Name' });
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://us-east1-foodmigo-v01-101.cloudfunctions.net/api/charge',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: token.id
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) this.props.setComplete(true);
  }
```

Lastly, set the disabled prop on your button in the parent based on the result (and replace any other instances of `this.state.complete` with the complete prop in the CheckoutForm as well, if necessary):

```
<Button type="submit" color="primary" disabled={loading || !this.state.complete}>
                  Fulfill Request
                  {loading && <CircularProgress />}
                </Button>
```

Can't test this but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 1. the ````setComplete(val) = () => {
    this.setState({
      complete: val
    })
  }```` function throws a parsing error: expected "{". 2. Shouldn't `````<CheckoutForm setComplete={this.setComplete} complete={this.state.complete}/>`````? 3. Correcting 1 to setComplete = (val) => & 2 throws if (response.ok) setComplete(true); is undefined.

Comment: Not sure about the parsing error, you're right about using ```this.setComplete```, I haven't used classes in a while.  Same thing for the third one, you'd have to use ```this.props.setComplete``` if it's not destructured from the props.  My bad, I couldn't set up a working example without all the components. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: There we go, that did it! setComplete = (val) => is the correct syntax. If I GitHub'd the project's frontend, are you altruistic enough to help out with the styling? ;) As you see if you visit foodmigo.com, the styling is absolutely horrid & that's the last major piece to this puzzle. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Updated the answer to fix the syntax errors.  And I'm not exactly a designer, but if you have any specific CSS questions I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you! I will comment back here as the questions arise.

Comment: If you have questions unrelated to this topic you should post a new question.